# "Multiple definition of.." "First defined here" in the same line in a data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, header-files

I have read many posts before posting this one, I couldnt find a solution because non of them (those I read) were on data structures.

I have two data structures (If it matter, a Heap and a UF). 
Both of them are implemented in the .h file.
I'm getting the "Multiple definition of.." "First defined here" errors only on member functions implemented outside of the class (such as `int UnionFind::Find(int i)` ) 
It happens for the c'tors and d'tors also, but when I implement them in the class itself, it disappear.
I really have no clue why it is happening. 
I have followed the includes in all of my files and there are no double includes or loops.

I'm also using an AVL tree, and it does not happen there, everything there is implemented in the .h file outside of the class.

These are the errors im getting :

```
/tmp/ccp8fP73.o: In function `UnionFind::Find(int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `UnionFind::Find(int)'
/tmp/ccVxSiPy.o:Elections.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccp8fP73.o: In function `UnionFind::Union(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x108): multiple definition of `UnionFind::Union(int, int)'
/tmp/ccVxSiPy.o:Elections.cpp:(.text+0x108): first defined here
```

If you need more info, please tell me.
Thank you

Comment: are you including *.cpp* files instead of *.h*?

Comment: You can't define functions outside the class in the header unless they are either templated or explicitly marked as inline. Otherwise you will get exactly the error you are seeing.

Comment: Oh.. The AVL is indeed templated..
Thank you very very very much.
Can you please explain me why I can't do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are doing things like this:

```
// C.h

class C
{
   void f(); // declaration of f; ok to include in many modules
};

// definition of f; must not exist in more than one module
void C::f()
{
}
```

That doesn't work because the definition of `f()` will wind up in every module that includes C.h, leading to exactly the linker error you describe. You can fix this by either marking `f()` as `inline`, or by moving the definition of `f()` to a separate cpp file.

There is one special case where this is allowed, and that's when `f()` is a template (either directly or because `C` is a template). In that case, the definition *must* be in the header so the compiler can know how to instantiate it for whatever type(s) you specify. This does make life difficult for the linker since you can and often do end up with the sorts of redundant definitions that would normally be errors (e.g if you use `f<int>()` in more than one module). Special behavior is needed to handle this.

Incidentally, the reason things work when you move the function bodies inside the class definition is because that has the effect of making them implicitly inline.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your templates manually..

//1. include the template code..

```
#include <template/list.tmpl.c>
```

// 2. instantiate the instances that use it..

```
#include "/c/viewer/src/ViewObject.h"
#include "/c/viewer/src/WindowAdaptor.h"
template class List<ViewObject>;
template class List<WindowAdaptor>;
```